# How do I define a dependency graph with unknown intermediate node names?

Tags: build, makefile, scons

I'm using a tool chain where I do not know the names of all of the intermediate files.

E.g. I know that I start out with a foo.s, and go through several steps to get a foo.XXXX.sym and a foo.XXXX.hex, buried way down deep.  And then running other tools on foo.XXXX.hex and foo.XXXX.sym, I eventually end up with something like final.results.

But, the trouble is that I don't know what the XXXX is.  It is *derived* from some other parameters, but may be significantly transformed away from them.

Now, after running the tool/steps that generate foo.XXXX.{sym,hex}, I now typically scan the overall result directory looking for foo.*.{sym,hex}.  I.e. I have code that can *recognize* the intermediate outputs, I just don't know exactly what the names will be.

I typically use make or scons - actually, I prefer scons, but my team highly prefers make. I'm open to other build tools.

What I want to do is be able to say (1) "make final.results", or "scons final.results", (2) and have it scan over the partial tree; (3) figure out that, while it does not know the full path, it definitely knows that it has to run the first step, (4) after that first step, look for and find the foo.XXX.* files; (5) and plug those into the dependency tree.

I.e. I want to finish building the dependency tree after the build has already started.

A friend got frustrated enough with scons' limitations in this area that he wrote his own build tool.  Unfortunately it is proprietary.

I guess that I can create a first build graph, say in make with many .PHONY targets, and then after I get through the first step, generate a new makefile with the new names, and have the first make invoke the newly generated second makefile.   Seems clumsy.  Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Could you not use implicit targets to fill in the parts of the names that you do not know? That is, have targets with '%'s.

Comment: @claytontstanley No, because you can't have a rule like `final.results: foo.%.sym`.

Comment: @claytonstanley: I have used implicit rules to do stuff like this. Beta provided one of the reasons. Another reason is that implicit rules sometimes cast too wide a net, and pick things up they should not.  Now, I do believe that there is a syntax to say "This implicit rule applies only to these specific files..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make constructs the graph before running any rule, so there won't be a perfect answer. Here are some reasonably clean solutions.

1) use PHONY intermediates and wildcards in the commands. (You can't use Make wildcards because make expands them before running rules.)

```
final.results: middle                                                         
    # build $@ using $(shell ls foo.*.sym) and $(shell ls foo.*.hex)

.PHONY: middle
middle: foo.s
    # build foo.XXXX.sym and foo.XXXX.hex from $<
```

2) Use recursive Make (which is not as bad as people say, and sometimes very useful.)

```
SYM = $(wildcard foo.*.sym)
HEX = $(wildcard foo.*.hex)

# Note that this is is the one you should "Make".
# I've put it first so it'll be the default.
.PHONY: first-step
first-step: foo.s
    # build foo.XXXX.sym and foo.XXXX.hex from $<
    @$(MAKE) -s final.results                                               

final.results:                                                                
    # build $@ using $(SYM) and $(HEX)
```

3) Similar to 2, but have a rule for the makefile which will cause Make to run a second time.

```
SYM = $(wildcard foo.*.sym)
HEX = $(wildcard foo.*.hex)

final.results:                                                                
    # build $@ using $(SYM) and $(HEX)

Makefile: foo.s
    # build foo.XXXX.sym and foo.XXXX.hex from $<
    @touch $@
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU make has an "auto-rexec" feature that you might be able to make use of.  See [How Makefiles Are Remade](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html#Remaking-Makefiles)

After make finishes reading all the makefiles (both the ones found automatically and/or on the command line, as well as all included makefiles), it will try to rebuild all its makefiles (using the rules it knows about).  If any of those makefiles are automatically rebuilt, then make will re-exec itself so it can re-read the newest versions of the makefiles/included files, and starts over (including re-trying to build all the makefiles).

It seems to me that you should be able to do something with this.  You can write in your main makefile and "-include foo.sym.mk" for example, and then have a rule that builds "foo.sym.mk" by invoking the tool on foo.s, then running your "recognized the next step" code and generate a "foo.sym.mk" file which defines a rule for the intermediate output that got created.  Something like (due to lack of specificity in your question I can't give true examples you understand):

```
SRCS = foo.s bar.s baz.s
-include $(patsubst %.s,%.sym.mk,$(SRCS))
%.sym.mk: %.s
        <compile> '$<'
        <recognize output and generate makefile> > '$@'
```

Now when make runs it will see that foo.sym.mk is out of date (if it is) using normal algorithms and it will rebuild foo.sym.mk, which as a "side effect" causes the foo.s file to be compiled.

And of course, the "foo.sym.mk" file can include ANOTHER file, which can recognize the next step, if necessary.

I'm not saying this will be trivial but it seems do-able based on your description.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have known/remembered this.